# Why did the prophet commit Zina?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

I recently came across [this article](https://archive.wikiislam.net/wiki/Mariyah_the_Sex_Slave_of_the_Holy_Prophet) in the Internet which said that the prophet committed Zina. The article was backed up by hadith proof as well. I was shocked. I have always thought of the Prophet as a wonderful person, but the respect I had for him melted like a candle. I lost my iman. Why did the prophet commit Zina?

Comment: The said article was on WikiIslam and named mariyah the sex slave of the prophet

Comment: The Prophet did not commit Zina nor is it possible for a prophet to commit Zina, anyone who ascribes such a thing to a Prophet does Kufr. If your respect for someone goes away so easily perhaps there is something wrong with you. Your question lacks any useful details and is not answerable.

Comment: @Aaliyah - So you are taking your information from wikiislam?? That website is full of misleading articles. You should avoid that website and sincerely repent to Allah for posting such a blasphemeous question.

Answer (score 2):

Assalam walikum warahmatulahi wabarakathahuu...
Dear sister
Please make sure of what u get information...
Our prophet Muhammad ( peace be upon him) .. he is a sinless messenger... And he contributed all his life to Allah  ( subhan WA tala) .. he is inspiration to all the ummahh..
Please who ever told this ... This is wrong.. our prophet is the sinless...  And there are thousands of articles which says wrong things we should not believe that ....And whoever says  lies about our prophet will eternally die in the hell fire.. so stop having this kind of questions... And repent to Allah (subhan WA tala) ... Allah will forgive you...
And say "ashadu an la ilaha illallah wa ashhadu anna muhammadan rasulu-llah"  and come back to Islam ..
Remember Allah is most merciful... And increase your Iman..
May Allah forgive our sins and accept our prayers..
May Allah take us to the straight path..
Jazzakallahu khair
Allah Hafiz